# Fedora 17 apache php show error reporting

Tags: php, apache, fedora

I can't seem to get apache or PHP on fedora to report errors.

Used xampp on Windows and that has all the settings just right for development, on fedora it's all just wrong I suspect but have no idea how to change it:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ilkjfdslfjsdl
phpinfo();
?>
```

Gives me a blank page and in firebug I can see http 500 server error is returned

When I do only phpnfo() I can see:

```
display_errors  Off Off
display_startup_errors  Off Off
```

I can see the php.ini there and edit it to:

```
display_errors = 1
display_startup_errors = 1
```

and have
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
In my script
Restart apache/httpd and still the same, quiet fail and a http 500 in firebug.
phpinfo keeps saying that display errors and startup errors are off whatever I try to do.

I would like to see my errors and warnings again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed anyting php with

```
yum remove php
yum remove php-*
```

Then installed php and php-xml php-pdo php-sql again

Edited the php.ini and restated apache, now phpinfo gives the right values and the right error warning reporting.

Comment: You've answered your own question and helped someone else. You might want to accept it as the answer.

Comment: Done, still wondered what would cause it but re installing it seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem.
Your solution worked for me.

After removing PHP and dependencies I did the following:

```
yum -y install php
yum -y install phpmyadmin
```

edited `php.ini`:

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd.service
```

and everything's fine now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something less radical worked for me, so I'm adding it to the potential solutions :

I edited the file `/etc/php.ini` and edited it so:

```
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
```

Those were the suggested development values, I'd suggest to *not do that* in a prod environment due to the possible leak of sensitive data.

Then I restarted `httpd`:

```
> systemctl restart httpd
```

It worked for me! I *have no idea* if you tried the main `/etc/php.ini` file or if setting the values to `1` even works, so just in case someone stumbles upon this problem you can attempt this solution before re-installing everything.